# Cause of rolling friction

Tags: rotational-dynamics, friction

1. Can you explain the cause of [rolling friction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance)?
2. Can you tell me why, while driving a bicycle, there is less rolling friction when  its tyres are fully inflated?

Comment: @Qmechanic: Sir, I think 

http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149409

is a duplicate of this.

Comment: @user36790 second part of the question is different

Answer (score 2):

You can get answer to your first question [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance#Primary_cause).

When tires are inflated less area of the tire comes in contact with the ground, and thus there is less kinetic friction.

Comment: Friction does not depend on the amount of surface area in contact between the moving bodies or (within certain limits) on the relative speed of the bodies. It does, however, depend on the magnitude of the forces holding the bodies together. 
Check this link -http://www.infoplease.com/encyclopedia/science/friction-factors-affecting-friction.html

Answer (score 0):

Friction is more if the Area of Contact of the tire is more.

When Air is completely filled in a Tire, the tire will be in lesser contact with the land as compared to when it has no or less air in it. This will lead to more friction by the tire, which will make it more difficult to drive the bicycle as compared to the earlier tire.