Why does a rolling ball slow down?
I have read the following answer and wish to know whether this is true because I thought the normal force will always pass through the centre of mass of the ball?

"A rolling ball slows down because the normal force does not pass exactly through the CM of the ball, but passes in front of the CM."



Could you post a link to the answer?

Gathering moss, unless the ball is made of stone...

Also: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149409/

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149409/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223283/2451 and links therein.

If the ball rolls without slipping while slowing down, there must be:

a net torque acting to reduce its rotation rate ($\tau = I \frac{d \omega}{d t}$) and
a net force acting to reduce its velocity ($F = m \frac{d v}{d t} = mr \frac{d \omega}{d t}$).

Here torque is $\tau$, moment of inertia is $I$, angular speed is $\omega$, mass is $m$, and speed is $v$. The contact forces (friction and normal force) produce the net torque about the centre of mass of the ball. Thus their sum cannot act through that centre of mass.
It would be possible for a perfectly rigid ball to slow down via rolling friction, even though the normal force acts through the centre of mass, if slipping were allowed. However, the case in the illustration you provide relies on the deformation of the ball. Therefore the normal to the point of contact does not pass through the centre of mass and a net torque results.

A perfectly rigid ball, rolling on a perfectly rigid surface would not slow down, (except from air resistance), but since there is no such thing in reality, that analogy says nothing meaningful. Your first sentence "If the ball rolls without slipping while slowing down," implies that the ball is not rigid (as all balls are not),  because it says it is slowing down.

@CharlesBretana your comment assumes that friction is impossible for a perfectly rigid object. However, friction can arise from factors other than the slight deformation of the overall shape of the ball shown in the diagram. These include interatomic and intermolecular forces, which don't require such a deformation. Admittedly, the dissipative mechanisms generally require conversion to thermal energy (i.e. vibrations) at the microscopic scale. You might extend the definition of "perfectly rigid" to preclude these. I wanted to highlight the case where tangential friction alone slows the ball.

@CharlesBretana You're right that the rigid ball can't slow down without slipping, as the friction and the torque it exerts would give rates of change in velocity and angular velocity which were inconsistent. I'll amend the answer to reflect this.

to play the game and assume that a perfectly rigid ball is even possible, (it is not), How can there be changes in interatomic and intermolecular forces if the position of every atom in the ball is fixed (perfectly rigid, right?). If that were true, then there would be friction even if the ball wasn't even rolling or moving as well. Clearly not possible. Forces, even interatomic/molecular electromagnetic forces, can only exist when there is a change in momentum, (F = dP/dT).

@CharlesBretana for example, two objects with extremely flat surfaces sliding past one another could experience friction that was not associated with the deformation of the profile of those surfaces but rather with interatomic/intermolecular forces. Yes, the dissipation of energy requires conversion to e.g. lattice vibrations (which you say are inconsistent with "perfect rigidity"). However, from a continuum standpoint, we could model the case as objects with infinite elastic modulus and some non-zero friction.

An extremely flat surface? A perfectly rigid ball is not flat. In fact, it would come into contact with an "extremely* flat surface at only one point. Ignoring the fact that this is not a realistic possible scenario, (no such objects exist or can exist), even if they could, the only interatomic or intermolecular forces would of necessity be absolutely symmetrical, because a rigid body is by definition symmetrical.  And if all such forces are laterally symmetrical, they cancel out, the ball velocity would not change, i.e., no change in momentum, and no acceleration.

Whenever you start to rely upon fictional objects, (like "perfectly" rigid balls or "friction-free" motion,, or "ideal" gases, or two-dimensional fluid flow), you need to be really careful about the conclusions you draw from any analysis of these scenarios. Because they assume something that is not physically possible, any and all conclusions are highly suspect and need to be applied very carefully, with great caution.

The ball slows down due to rolling resistance. That resistance equals the normal force times the coefficient of rolling resistance.
Rolling resistance occurs due to inelastic deformation of the ball material. The effect of that deformation is to dissipate heat from internal friction and cause an asymmetric distribution of the normal pressure, thus shifting the location of the normal force.
Hope this helps.

Ball material and/or the material of the surface on which it rolls. A glass marble rolls about as freely on a deep pile carpet as a ball of plumber's putty rolling on a granite counter top.

Many thanks for your answer.

When a ball or other object is sitting still, the normal force does pass through the center of mass. You can see this must be so from your diagram. If it did not, there would be a torque and the ball would rotate.
Stand up. The normal force originates from each point on the bottom of your feet. Each of those forces creates a torque. Since you are standing still, the total torque is $0$.
You stand up by pushing the floor away with your legs. Push a little less with one leg. You immediately begin to rotate.
For more, see Toppling of a cylinder on a block and Why do we assume weight acts through the center of mass?

Many thanks for your answer.

See in the figure center of mass has nothing to do with it, since this ball will slow down due to the rotational resistance and frictional forces applying on it (F) (I feel sorry for not putting a vector sign).
the center of mass doesn't play any role in decelerating the ball but they are the microscopic interaction and energy loss due to deformation which creates a gradual deceleration. The center of mass's role is more about the distribution of mass in the ball, which affects how it rolls but not why it slows down.
Thank you

The aspects mentioned in the question are one of the major reasons for rotational resistance.

Well, because of the force between the ball, and the surface it is rolling on, the ball, and the surface deforms a small amount, and as it is rolling, both deformations must propagate forward with the ball. Therefore, the force, and the size of the deformation in front of the ball must be slightly larger than they are behind the ball. This causes the aggregate sum of the forces between the ball and the surface to be slightly forward of the point directly underneath the center of mass.

Many thanks for your answer.
