# How far does a teflon ball roll on a very even surface?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, kinetic-theory

As teflon has a minimal frictional coefficient of about 0.04, how far does a ball made of teflon roll on a even surface in comparison to another ball (made of wood or iron, for example), when pushed by a specific force?

Edit: The surface is solid and not that much deformable, such as wood.

Comment: How deformable is the surface? One of the primary components of rolling resistance is deformation of the surface.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149409/what-is-the-cause-of-rolling-friction-why-is-it-less-than-sliding-friction

Comment: Should air resistance be included in this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coefficient of friction describes the behaviour of sliding one surface over another, it's important to use the (generally much lower) co-efficient of rolling resistance.

All other things being equal in the comparison, and as a result of how it is  defined, the retarding force is proportional to the coefficient of rolling friction. 
Since work = force x distance, to do the work necessary to bring the ball to a halt (to cancel its kinetic energy including that due to rotation) is given by d=w/f. Distance is therefore inversely proportional to co-efficient of resistance.

The comparitive equation is thus

$$\frac{d_1}{d_2}=\frac{c_2}{c_1}$$

d=distance, c=coefficient of rolling resistance.

Note: The following must be equal to cancel out in the comparison: rigidity of ball and surface, initial kinetic energy (as supplied by the initial force). Air resistance and any other retarding forces. force due to gravity.

Thus if you now choose a material to compare Teflon too, and you know their rolling resistances on the surface used, you could predict the answer. I couldn't find such specific figures, but there are some examples of real world rolling resistances [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance#Rolling_resistance_coefficient_examples). 
I suppose to try to select similar materials, the steel bearing is a low value rolling resistance, objects have to be specially designed to have 100 times that value.

So I estimate the answer you want might be *very aproximately* "The teflon ball will roll an order of magnitude (10x) further."